# How to stop a Shader from distorting a texture

Tags: c++, glsl, shader, sfml

I am trying to learn how to use shaders and use GLSL. One of the shaders is working but is distorting the texture of the sprite it's working on. I'm doing this all on SFML.

Distorted texture on left, actual texture on right:

[image: img]

The problem comes from this line

When I started the texture was being rendered upside down but subtracting the y component of the cordinates from 1 fixed that issue. The line that is causing the issue is

```
vec2 texCoord = (gl_FragCoord.xy / sourceSize.xy);
```

Where the sourceSize is a uniform passing in the resolution of something as a vec2. I've been passing in various values into this and getting different distorted versions of the texture. I was wondering if there was a way a ratio to pass in or something to avoid this distortion.

Texture Size in Pixels: 512x512
Passed in values for the above image: 512x512

Shader

```
uniform sampler2D       source;
uniform vec2            sourceSize;
uniform float           time;


void main( void )
{   
     vec2 texCoord = (gl_FragCoord.xy / sourceSize.xy); //Gets the pixel position in a range of 0.0 to 1
     texCoord = vec2 (texCoord.x,1.0-texCoord.y);//Inverts the y co ordinate


     vec4 Color = texture2D(source, texCoord);//Gets the current pixture colour


     gl_FragColor = Color;//Output
}
```

Comment: OpenGL texture [0,0] corner is left-down not top-left as you can expect. You can vertically mirror your image before load it into texture, or change UV coordinates.

Comment: Thanks but it's already doing that.
(texCoord.x,1.0-texCoord.y);//Inverts the y co ordinate
This sets the texture to the right way vertically. The issue I'm having is that 
vec2 texCoord = (gl_FragCoord.xy / sourceSize.xy);
Is giving back a distorted texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Posting it here for if other need the help.
Changing

```
vec4 Color = texture2D(source, texCoord);//Gets the current pixture colour
```

To

```
vec4 Color = texture2D(source, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);//Gets the current pixture colour
```

Will fix the distortion effect.